# Reading oddly-formatted XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need some help with reading an oddly-formatted XML file. Because of the way the nodes and attributes are structured, I keep running into XMLException errors (at least, that's what the output window is telling me; my breakpoints refuse to fire so that I can check it). Anyway, here's the XML. Anyone experienced anything like this before?

```
<ApplicationMonitoring>
<MonitoredApps>
        <Application>
            <function1 listenPort="5000"/>
        </Application>
        <Application>
            <function2 listenPort="6000"/>
        </Application>
</MonitoredApps>
<MIBs>
    <site1 location="test.mib"/>
</MIBs> 
<Community value="public"/>
<proxyAgent listenPort="161" timeOut="2"/>
</ApplicationMonitoring>
```

Cheers

EDIT: Current version of the parsing code (file path shortened - Im not actually using this one):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(@"..\..\..\ApplicationMonitoring.xml");

string port = xml.DocumentElement["proxyAgent"].InnerText;
```

Comment: `<ApplicationMonitoring>` doesn't appear to have a closing tag

Comment: If that is the whole document, that is illegal XML because the `ApplicationMonitoring` root element never closes, which might explain your problem.  Is that the entirety of what you are parsing?

Comment: It's not valid XML since there's no closing `<ApplicationMonitoring>` tag.

Comment: Not, that's just a bady copy on my part. It has a closing tag.

Comment: @Skulmuk:  Then you should make sure it exists in the question...

Comment: Turns out it was the format i entered it in, not my copying ability (missed the 4 spaces)

Comment: In addition to the above mentioned excellent points I'm intrigued why you mentioned "oddly-formatted XML". Were you aware that it was badly formed or are you just referring to its layout? If the latter then you should probably be aware that layout doesn't really effect parsing of XML in general, I think.

Comment: What exceptions do you keep running into?

Comment: @Chris It's not my XML, it's pre-made by some external software, but thanks for clearing that up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in loading the XML is that `xml.LoadXml` expects you to pass the xml document as a string, not a file reference.

Try instead using:

```
xml.Load(@"..\..\..\ApplicationMonitoring.xml");
```

Essentially in your original code you are telling it that your xml document is

```
..\..\..\ApplicationMonitoring.xml
```

And I'm sure you can now see why there is a parse exception. :) I've tested this with your xml document and the modified load and it works fine (except for the issue that Only Bolivian Here pointed out with the fact that your inner Text is not going to return anything.

For completeness you probably want:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"..\..\..\ApplicationMonitoring.xml");
string port = xml.DocumentElement["proxyAgent"].Attributes["listenPort"].Value;
//And to get stuff more specifically in the tree something like this
string function1 = xml.SelectSingleNode("//function1").Attributes["listenPort"].Value;
```

Note the use of the Value property on the attribute and not the ToString method which won't do what you are expecting.

Exactly how you extract the data from the xml is probably dependant on what you are doing with it. For example you may want to get a list of Application nodes to enumerate over with a foreach by doing this `xml.SelectNodes("//Application")`.

If you are having trouble with extdacting stuff though that is probably the scope of a different question since this was just about how to get the XML document loaded.

Comment: That worked nicely ;) Might I ask how you'd propose reading the function names, seeing as how each is different? I doubt xml.DocumentElement[""] will work....

Comment: I've added a bit more in on the selecting (including making the attribute selection explicit since using an integer is a bit fragile if attributes change order or something). Don't forget you can vote up an answer that is helpful to you and I'd also suggest asking any questions about extracting the data via XPath in another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
xml.DocumentElement["proxyAgent"].InnerText;
```

The proxyAgent element is self closing. InnerText will return the string inside of an XML element, in this case, there is no inner elements.

You need to access an attribute of the element, not the InnerText.

Comment: You mean like this?

string port = xml.DocumentElement["proxyAgent"].Attributes[0].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string port = xml.GetElementsByTagName("ProxyAgent")[0].Attributes["listenPort"].ToString();
```

Or use Linq to XML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

And... your XML is not malformed...